# How can I make my Knockout.js components append to the page without erasing/overwriting any old bindings?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-components, knockout-templating

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/27/

Basically I have a Knockout.js component that uses a template:

**JavaScript:**

```
ko.components.register('sublist', {
    synchronous: true,
    viewModel: function (params) {},
    template: {
        element: 'my-component-template'
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="component:{name:'sublist',params:{vm:sidebarVm}}" class=""></ul>
<template id="my-component-template">
    <!-- ko foreach: sidebarVm.stepList.steps-->
      <li data-bind="html: message"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</template>
```

I have multiple ViewModels that the user can load into that template with certain button clicks. As I have it now, when the user loads a new ViewModel, it overwrites the old one.

**Desired Functionality:** When the user clicks a button to load a new Viewmodel, those new list elements `<li>` get appended rather than replacing the existing ones. How?? In the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/27/), there should be a total of 6 list elements in one list.

**EDIT:** Maybe I have to go somewhere along the lines in this new *fiddle*? Maybe something like this would allow me to instantiate multiple ViewModels within the `<ul>`.  http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/32/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tbh, your usage of knockout is not as it is meant to be. If it are really ViewModels then make a "host" MainViewModel that manages the other ViewModels

```
  var MainMenuViewModel = function () {
    this.viewModels = ko.observableArray();
    this.viewModels.push(new ViewModel1());

    this.load=function(){
        this.viewModels.push(new ViewModel1());
    };
}
```

see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r2hsvsdg/1/

btw, you can also handle the click logic using knockout

better fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/r2hsvsdg/4/

Comment: I am new to Knockout and I had the feeling I was writing some janky code. I think if I can re-format my project to the style you have here then it will make things a lot more readable and usable. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!